# Do any English words end in /ɒ/, a short o?

Tags: pronunciation

The question was prompted by trying to find an English analogue to the many words in Welsh that end with /ɒ/ (today's example: [crwydro](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crwydro) = wander).  This sound is after all common in English at the beginning or in the middle of a word (*ox*, *not*).

I can't think of any common word in reasonably standard English that ends this way. As a Londoner originally I'm prone to t-glottalisation, which leads to something pretty close.  Words spelt *–o* generally seem to end with the highly variable (so I haven't tried to give IPA) ɢᴏᴀᴛ vowel.

I'm approaching this from a Southern British perspective, but other common accents/dialects are also interesting. The original version of this question was confused by using IPA examples that were based on pronouncing *cot* to match *caught* but didn't say so explicitly.

So do any English words end with this sound?

Comment: The word *law* (as well as *claw, floor,* and numerous others) ends with /ɔ/, at least in some British dialects.  I assume you're worried about /ɒ/.

Comment: @PeterShor you may well be right, I can never remember my IPA vowels so have to look them up and may have hit an American source

Comment: Looking online, the British vowels are currently moving around, *law* going from /ɔ/ to /o/, and *pot* going from /ɒ/ to /ɔ/, so it seems you're not actually wrong. But using /ɔ/ to represent this vowel is confusing.

Comment: I would say no. /ɒ/ and /ɔː/ are often considered to be the checked and unchecked counterparts of each other (like /ɪ/ and /iː/). As a checked vowel, /ɒ/ can occur only in closed syllables, so you’ll never get a word that ends in it. There are lots of words that end in /ɔː/, but (and this relates to what @Peter wrote too) /ɔː/ is always realised long in English, whereas Welsh /ɔ/ is short. English has no short [ɔ] at all, so no words to end in it either. English /ɔ/ is also further back than Welsh /ɔ/, but that’s perhaps going into too much phonetic detail.

Comment: @PeterShor I've tried to clean it up

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet American English has no phonemic length marker for vowels, so the *saw, law, caw, claw, draw, flaw, jaw, raw, thaw* set all have a consonant phoneme followed by a lone /ɔ/.

Comment: @tchrist That’s why I specifically said that /ɔː/ (I always write the length marker in the phonemes for consistency and maximum cross-dialect clarity) is always _realised_ long. It may not be long phonemically, but it is invariably long phonetically, which the Welsh vowel isn’t. If we ignore that, then yes, there are many words that end in this sound; but acoustically, Welsh /ɔ/ and English /ɔː/ are **very** different. The final vowel in _saw_, etc., is acoustically as far from that in _crwydro_ as the final vowel in _know_ is from that in Spanish _no_.

Comment: I feel like it's a speech pattern thing, in addition to a full-fledged language thing. Even if a word technically ended in a short *ox*-like vowel, for most English speakers it would have adapted to standard pronunciation by becoming a *law*-like vowel. Not because it's correct or incorrect, but because most modern English speakers aren't used to speaking that way.

Comment: Do words like *grandma* and *haha* fit the bill?

Comment: @Hellion, I've never come across an accent in which they share a vowel with *cot* unless also with *caught*, which then doesn't fit.

Comment: @ChrisH I would say that they do in my (generic midwestish) accent... *Gran-mah*, not *gran-maw*; same *-ah-* as in *ox*, *spot* or *bother*, which is readily distinguishable from *-aw-* as in *law*, *caught*, or *fall*.

Comment: @Hellion, those vowels are certainly distinguishable, but that's not a merger I'm familiar with. *Grandma* is normally /ɑː/ at the end, while *ox* uses /ɒ/, and that's what I'm looking for. I'm trying to think of a minimal pair to ask how you distinguish these, but that's harder than it might be because anything I come up with could be told apart by the presence of an *r* in a rhotic accent

Comment: @ChrisH: The word *father* has /ɑ/ for many rhotic speakers. For me and many other American English speakers, "father" rhymes with "bother": both have /ɑ/.

Comment: @sumelic not knowing the full range of (even common) accents is why I led with IPA in the title (although it took me a couple of goes to get it right due to lack of expertise). Does this mean that you don't have /ɒ/ in anything?

Comment: @ChrisH: Yes; I don't have /ɒ/ as a distinct sound. It's possible that my pronunciation of /ɑ/ before a "dark l" sound (in words like ***a**ll, b**a**ll, d**o**llar, ko**a**la*) is somewhere around [ɒ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, English words do not end with any of the stressed "short" vowel sounds (/ɒ/, /æ/, /ɛ/, /ʌ/, /ɪ/, /ʊ/). This is not an absolutely exceptionless rule: interjections may not follow it (for example, I have /æ/ in "yeah" and /ʌ/ in "duh"), and I don't find it particularly difficult to pronounce nonsense words ending in stressed /ɪ/, for example.

In American English, historical "short o" has been merged into the originally "long" vowel sound /ɑ/, so the original restriction on the distribution of the "short o" sound no longer applies, at least not on the surface level (the word *spa* ends in the same sound /ɑ/ that is used for the "short o" sound in *pod,* so *pod* and "spa'd" rhyme).

Furthermore, as far as I know there is no dialect of English where the sound /ɒ/ is in common use in fully unstressed open syllables. (Unlike /ɪ/ and /ʊ/, which some accents use in words like *read**y*** or *grad**u**al*.)

So I don't think you'll be able to find any word ending in /ɒ/.

The symbol /ɔ/ is most commonly used in transcriptions of English to represent a vowel sound distinct from the sound of "short o". It is also transcribed /ɔː/ (with the IPA length marker "ː")  in the context of British English to indicate that it functions as a "long vowel" in the British English vowel system. This vowel sound does occur word-finally, in various words spelled with *-aw* (*law, claw, raw, straw*), and in "non-rhotic" accents also in words spelled with *-oar, -ore* such as *roar, more, tore, bore* (and some words spelled with *-oor* such as *door* and *floor*).

The British English /ɒ/ phoneme ("short o") may be realized as the IPA phonetic vowel [ɔ], and the British English /ɔː/ phoneme may be realized as the IPA phonetic vowel [oː], but purely phonetic transcriptions are not very commonly encountered, particularly not when discussing restrictions on the distribution of sounds in a language's sound system. (Contrariwise, in American English the phoneme transcribed /ɔ/ may be realized phonetically as something like [ɒ]—even in accents where it is not merged with the open unrounded /ɑ/ sound, it often is relatively close to it phonetically.) This mainly comes up as an issue when people are trying to compare vowel sounds between different languages: for example, comparing English "o" sounds to those of Italian, French, or German.

Comment: *Duh* I’ll grant you, but surely your *yeah* is realized with a centralizing diphthong finish in [jæə̯], isn’t it? Mine certainly is.

Comment: @tchrist: Different speakers evidently perceive different phonemes in the word *yeah.* I've seen it transcribed as /jɛ/ and as /jɛə/, in addition to the transcription that you propose and my transcription of /jæ/. To me, I think there isn't a phonemic distinction between /æ/ and /æə/, although [æə̯] might be used in my speech as a realization of the /æ/ phoneme.

Comment: @sumelic: possibly /æ/, /ɛ/, and all those other variants are merged in English when they're at the end of a word. Of course, we have so few examples that maybe it's impossible to tell.

Comment: What you’re describing seems similar to how phonetic off-glides in (esp. word-final) closed vowels like phonemic /e/ and /o/ are sometimes perceived by ESL learners  as phonetic diphthongs [eɪ] and [oʊ]. But native speakers think of them as simple vowels. I bet that that’s what you are doing here with your /jæ/ with its two phonemes: the [jæə̯] version is just an automatic compensation that (some? many?) native speakers make without thinking of it as a separate phoneme. Just as you will find no minimal pair in English for /o/ vs /oʊ/,  I bet you will also find none for /æ/ vs /æə/

Comment: @tchrist: Minimal pair for /o/ vs /oʊ/: *shoring*  and *show ring*. And maybe *touring* and *toe ring*. Of course, this only works for some varieties of English.

Comment: @PeterShor No, when tchrist writes /o/, he’s referring to the phoneme found in the word _know_ as usually transcribed for AmE. _Shoring_ and _show ring_ would be phonetically /ˈʃɔrɪŋ/ and /ˈʃo.ˌrɪŋ/ in AmE. Phonemic /o/ is phonetically [oʊ] (or something along those lines—the details differ, of course) in AmE.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: there are accents of AmE where it makes more sense to analyze “shore” as having the rhyme /or/, but the “shoring-show ring” distinction can be analyzed as a syllabification difference, or something along those lines, since such a distinction is necessary in other contexts anyway (“night rate” vs “nitrate” etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a few do, but not very many. Common examples are *saw, law, claw, draw, flaw, jaw, raw, thaw*, or a crow’s *caw*.

This is because for the most part, /ɔ/ patterns like a “checked” vowel (meaning a lax vowel like the ones that also prototypically occur in DRESS, KIT, HAM, PUT) in that it doesn’t like to end a syllable without a consonant or glide following it. So words like *soft* and *loft* and *coughed*, or *sawyer* and *lawyer*, are more likely than just plain *saw* and *law* type words.

Normally a word-final tense vowel like phonemic /o/ that isn’t reduced will take a terminal glide phonetically, so an extra /w/ and sometimes written phonetically as [oʊ].

Sometimes words spelled with ‹a› are pronounced /ɔ/, as in one regional pronunciation of the stressed syllable in the city of *Chicago* [ʃɨ ˈ**kʰɔ** goʷ], or even *grandma* in the eye-dialect spelling of *grandmaw*.

This ends up being reflected in spellings like *fellow*. Notice though how when that gets reduced in the unstressed position, it gets spelled *fella*, reflecting that it has become an open back unrounded /ɑ/, phonetically reduced further even to schwa.

The other kind of reduction we see in words adapted into English from other languages where they had originally ended in /o/ is for them to go to /u/. This happens in words like *buckaroo* from Spanish *vaquero* or *vindaloo* probably from Portuguese *vin(ho) d’alho*, or even in *lasso* from Spanish *lazo* but pronounced /ˈlæsu/ with /u/ in English rather than /ˈlɑso/ as though it were Spanish.

Comment: It seems like I got my IPA in a muddle when I first wrote the question, because the distinction between the examples in your first paragraph and the sound that prompted the question is clear to my (untrained) ear, but not in the question